# Check if an element is closed using a discrete tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

I am getting the child nodes of en element and i want to check if the tags can actually contain text. For example:

```
<br />, <img />
```

Should return false and

```
<span></span>, <div></div>, <li></li>
```

should return true. Thanks!

Comment: What about `<video>` (which can contain text, but only as alternative content in case the video fails)?. (There are other elements with similar rules in HTML).

Comment: Any element that can contain text in any form or way, so also <video>. It's just so I don't get an error later on when writing innerHTML / innerText (or any other function that requires a closed tag) to the elements.

Comment: You could check whether `el.childNodes.length > 0`, but generally there is no difference between an empty and a self-closing element in the DOM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to detect how a tag was written in the code, since when the JavaScript runs, the HTML code has already been parsed into DOM objects.

However, your question seems to be more about whether a particular element type can contain text. This simple test will give you an answer per element type:

```
function canElementContainText(tagname) {
    try {
        var e = document.createElement(tagname);
        return e.outerHTML.indexOf("/") != -1;
    } catch (ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For instance `canElementContainText("div")` returns `true` and `canElementContainText("img")` returns `false`.

You can then pass the `tagName` property of any element to this function to test it.

```
var result = canElementContainText(myElement.tagName);
```

Comment: Instead of using innerText, try `appendChild(document.createTextNode(...)`

Comment: Im trying that now, but firefox allows you to append anything to an `<img>`

Comment: Replaced with cross-browser compatible method tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE11. Tested on http://jsfiddle.net/alancnet/tdBf3/

Comment: Nonetheless of all, updated script not working for every html tags, like `video`,`strong`... !

Comment: At this point, I would have to ask what problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps there is a better way to go about it? For instance, you could create an object that already has the answers: `{ div: true; img: false, video: false, span: true, ... }`... Or perhaps you can augment the faulty approach with such an object...

Comment: I just mentioned that script doesn't work properly, in my opinion better way is to do like I've posted

Comment: And the point of that kind of set could be very useful in dynamically generated `DOM`

Answer (score 3):

Following script works just fine (cross-browser issue resolved):

```
function containTxt(tag) {
    var tags = /^(img|video)$/i; // any values which will be in `tags` set will be treated as they can't have a text value
    return !tags.test(tag);
}

console.log(containTxt("img")); // returns false
console.log(containTxt("div")); // returns true
```

Comment: This is good to check if a Tag actually *contains* text, but not if it *can* contain text. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

use that:

```
canContainText: function(node) {
    if(node.nodeType === 3){
        return true;
    }
    if(node.nodeType === 1){
        return /<[^>]+><\/[^>]+>/gi.test(document.createElement(node.nodeName.toLowerCase())).outerHTML;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Could use RegEx:

```
// these are samples, get elements text using element.innerHTML;
var one = "<a href='something'>Links</a>";
var two = "Lorem ipsum dolor";

function check(str){
    return str.match(/<[a-zA-Z]+.*>(.|\n)*<\/[a-zA-Z]+>/) ? true : false;
}

console.log(check(one)); // true
console.log(check(two)); // false
```

Comment: you check whether a tag actually contains html. that's not what the op  asked for